# Leetcode 1249. Minimum Remove to Make Valid Parentheses

Tags: ios, swift, string

I need help in understanding the swift implementation to the problem below. The part I do not understand is the for loop; the if part of the loop appends the index of "(" to stack array I am not sure how the else if works to pop elements from the stack.Also with the final loop, what does it do?

*Given a string s of '(' , ')' and lowercase English characters.
Your task is to remove the minimum number of parentheses ( '(' or ')', in any positions ) so that the resulting parentheses string is valid and return any valid string.
Formally, a parentheses string is valid if and only if:

It is the empty string, contains only lowercase characters, or

It can be written as AB (A concatenated with B), where A and B are valid strings, or

It can be written as (A), where A is a valid string.*

```
func minRemoveToMakeValid(_ s: String) -> String {
    var arraySrting = s.map({String($0)})
    var stacks = [Int]()
    
    for i in 0..<arraySrting.count{
        if arraySrting[i] == "("{
            stacks.append(i)
        }
        else if arraySrting[i] == ")" && stacks.popLast() == nil{
            arraySrting[i] = ""
        }
    }
    for stack in stacks {
        arraySrting[stack] =  ""
    }
    
    return arraySrting.joined()
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those variable names are spelled wrong and incorrect. This is the same thing with optional characters instead of the language-agnostic solution of using empty strings.

```swift
import Algorithms // `compacted()` is better than `compactMap { $0 }`

func minRemoveToMakeValid(_ s: String) -> String {
  var characters: [Character?] = Array(s)
  var unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices: [Array.Index] = []

  func removeUnpairedParenthesis(at index: Array.Index) {
    characters[index] = nil
  }

  for (index, character) in characters.enumerated() {
    switch character {
    case "(":
      unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices.append(index)
    case ")":
      switch unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices.popLast() {
      case .some:
        // This `)` was paired with a previous `(`.
        break
      case nil:
        // This `)` was not.
        removeUnpairedParenthesis(at: index)
      }
    default:
      break
    }
  }

  unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices.forEach(removeUnpairedParenthesis)
  
  return .init(characters.compacted())
}
```

You can just build up `characters` more directly though, and `unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices` can be a `Set`.

```swift
func minRemoveToMakeValid(_ s: String) -> String {
  var characters: [Character?] = []
  var unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices: Set<Int> = []

  for (index, character) in s.enumerated() {
    switch character {
    case "(":
      unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices.insert(index)
    case ")":
      switch unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices.popFirst() {
      case .some:
        // This `)` was paired with a previous `(`.
        break
      case nil:
        // This `)` was not.
        characters.append(nil)
        continue
      }
    default:
      break
    }

    characters.append(character)
  }

  return .init(
    characters.enumerated().compactMap {
      unmatchedOpenParenthesisIndices.contains($0.offset)
        ? nil
        : $0.element
    }
  )
}
```